# opengl java glTexCoord problems. am i not doing it right?

Tags: java, opengl, sprite-sheet

Ok, i am a self taught programmer, and i am trying to use lwjgl and slik-utils to make a library to provide tools to make games. i have been trying to make a spritesheet, and i am using glTexCoord() to try to get only a part of the image. But to my best efforts, i thas not worked. here is the draw code.

```
public SpriteSheet draw(int x, int y, Point2D p)
    {
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    float x1 = p.posX * size + (size / 2F);
    float y1 = p.posY * size + (size / 2F);
    float d = 1F / texture.getImageHeight();
    int i = size / 2;
    //Texture centers for coords
    float x2 = x1 * d;
    float y2 = y1 * d;
    float d1 = i * d;

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(x2 - d1, y2 - d1);
    //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL2D.vertex(x - i, y - i);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(x2 - d1, y2 + d1);
    //GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL2D.vertex(x - i, y + i);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(x2 + d1, y2 + d1);
    //GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL2D.vertex(x + i, x + i);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(x2 + d1, y2 - d1);
    //GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL2D.vertex(x - i, y + i);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
    //TexturedQuad2D t = new TexturedQuad2D(32, 32, Color.black, texture);
    //t.draw(x, y);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are doing it wrong :)
your x and y are your world space coordinates and not your texture coordinate space, imagine your x and y being on coordinates 700, 800 and your texture size is 512. 700 / 512 = 1.4, texture coordinate go from 0 to 1.
so as first step try to set your texture coordinates with 0 and 1.

```
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
```

now as second step start to figure out how to calculate a portion of your texture coordinates
so if we have a sprite with 2 frames we go from 0 to 0.5 for first frame and 0.5 to 1 for second

```
//first frame would be
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.5, 1);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.5, 0);
//second frame would be
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.5, 0);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.5, 1);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
 GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
```

Now as third step write a sprite class to calculate this coordinates for you!

ps. on second notice are you enabling textures for OpenGL anywhere *GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);* to get any texture at all?

Comment: I have enables 2d textures, and what do you mean using my world coordinates? I don't think I am using those to calculate texture coords

Comment: I have enables 2d textures, and what do you mean using my world coordinates? I don't think I am using those to calculate texture coords. You may be confusing the point2D as the draw coords. The x and y passed to the method are the draw coords, and the point is the sprite coords on the actual image. So if the point was 0, 0, then it should draw the first square at the bottom left of the image. The square should have length and width of the size variable. I know for a fact everything is correctly calculated.

Comment: I did misunderstood the coordinates.
Do you see anything on screen at all? if not try disabling the faceculling <i>GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);</i>  
alos with p being 0, 0 it should be correct i think, have to recheck the coordinate order, but however with p being for example 256, 256 it is incorrect, because then you will get with size 256; 256*256 + (256/2)

Comment: The point system I set up does not work like that in this case. It splits the texture up int squares of the size, then say 0, 0 is the bottom left square, and then in a 256x256 texture, with size being 16, the top right square would be 15, 15

Comment: i tried disabling face culling while drawing, to no avail. I honestly do not see what is going wrong :(